# Can't Start Oracle SQL Developer in windows 7 64 bit

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have installed the **`SQL Developer`** in my system, while starting **`SQL developer`** (starting by double clicking on `sqldeveloper.exe` file.)

I am getting the below attached error:

[image: Unable to find the following configuration-product.conf].

How can i resolve this issue? Any prerequisites missing? Any kind of help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved by using latest version SQL Developer (sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78-x64.zip).